# Stuck on AsyncPost in Web API

Tags: asynchronous, controller

I am really stuck on this as I have searched far and wide for a solution for an asyncpost using Web API but couldnt find anything. Essentially, its got to make a POST call using HttpClient to the relevant controller class AddMenuItem using Web API but it just doesn't work. It simply throws an error of a 404 Error and cannot see the controller method. Any reasons why and solution for this would be very helpful!

```
    // Async Post Call
    public static async void asyncPost()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var values = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
                values.Add("ItemName", "Pepperoni Pizza");
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

                string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";
                HttpResponseMessage response3 = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress + "api/values/AddMenuItem", content);

                if (response3.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // Do something...
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        }
    }


    // POST api/values 
    public void AddMenuItem([FromBody]string itemName)
    {
        //Should go in here when PostAync is called
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `async void`; use `async Task` instead.

```
public static async Task PostAsync()
```

Then your controller can call it with `await`:

```
public async Task AddMenuItem([FromBody]string itemName)
{
  await PostAsync(..);
}
```